# How to read from a kwallet map per kwalletcli?

Tags: bash, kde, kwalletcli, kwallet

I try to use `kwalletcli` to access a password in a bash script. I know how to access ordinary passwords. But in the kwalletmanager GUI tool there is another kind of entries which is called *Maps*. Look at the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I access one of the entries below this item?